# functions.php adding item to end of menu. I want to change position

Tags: menus

I found a function in my template that is adding a register button to the end of my menu.  I'm wondering if there is any way to make this function add the register button to the beginning of my menu items?

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'vertoh_wp_nav_menu_items', 10, 2);

function vertoh_wp_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {
    $widget_ef_registration = get_option('widget_ef_registration');

    if ($args->theme_location == 'primary' && is_active_widget(false, false, 'ef_registration') && is_array($widget_ef_registration)) {
        foreach ($widget_ef_registration as $key => $reg_widget) {
            if (empty($reg_widget)) {
                unset($widget_ef_registration[$key]);
                update_option('widget_ef_registration', $widget_ef_registration);
            } elseif (isset($reg_widget['registrationshowtopmenu']) && $reg_widget['registrationshowtopmenu'] == 1) {
                $registration_topmenu_url = !empty($reg_widget['registrationtopmenuurl']) ? $reg_widget['registrationtopmenuurl'] : '#tile_registration_anchor';
                $items .= '<li class="register"><a href="' . $registration_topmenu_url . '" class="section-button">' . stripslashes($reg_widget['registrationtopmenutext']) . '</a></li>';
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP operators you can change:

```
$items .= '<li class="register"><a href="' . $registration_topmenu_url . '" class="section-button">' . stripslashes($reg_widget['registrationtopmenutext']) . '</a></li>';
```

To

```
$rbutton = '<li class="register"><a href="' . $registration_topmenu_url . '" class="section-button">' . stripslashes($reg_widget['registrationtopmenutext']) . '</a></li>';
$items = $rbutton . $items;
```

Comment: thanks for your help with this!  i changed my code and got an error:
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'

Comment: changed to this:
`$rbutton = '<li class="register"><a href="' . $registration_topmenu_url . '" class="section-button">' . stripslashes($reg_widget['registrationtopmenutext']) . '</a></li>';
    $items = $rbutton . $items;`